# Bootstrap modal not adjusting height to content(Table)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a bootstrap modal with tabs, the tabs have various content that's working.

Now i'm trying to add two tables to a new tab, but the modal height does just adjust to the table height:

[image]

This is the html for the tab:

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="AppsTab">
                            <div id="appmodalcontainer">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Enhet</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>
                                                                                        <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>
                                                                                        <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>
                                                                                        <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>
                                                                                        <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>

                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Enhet</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Hej 1</td></tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <hr />
                    </div>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: try to add `display: inline-table;` to the modal style

Comment: DON'T give a fix height to a table or models, here i tried your code and its working perfectly with my model.